# Is there something equivalent to PrimeFaces for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, primefaces, similarity

I'm being a ASP.NET developer over years but recently I started to work with some PrimeFaces solutions with JSF 2.0. I haven't nothing to complain about it.

It is worth *emphasizing a few points that did ​​me likes the PrimeFaces*: many components, easy to use, fully based on jQuery and jQuery UI (which are very important to me) and very focused on web standards (even more important to me).

*But there are some cases that I would really want my server-side with ASP.NET*. I don't want to start a discussion here about advantages between JSP and ASP.NET, both has many motives to be used.

Well, the standard ASP.NET components aren't jQuery based, aren't themable with jQuery UI Themes, aren't fully based on web standards (a big problem) and the variability is much more simple (there aren't Carousel, Accordion, Captcha, Slider, Spinner, etc, etc, etc).

**EDIT**

Continuing the saga, the @Raynos answers inspired me to study lighter possibilities, like the suggested [manos](https://github.com/jacksonh/one). But I really would like something a little more automated, at least in the HTML generation for common controls. Someone known working CRUD samples for manos or additional modules supporting this task?

Recalling that the main question is still open anyway: **Do you know any UI Framework for ASP.NET based on the same ideas of PrimeFaces, prefered open-source like it is?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose we cannot answer your question with something simple. As showed by other answers, unfortunately *we don't have in ASP.NET any UI framework fully web standards based*.

You surelly have that choice about not using ASP.NET but another .NET Framework based engine. I really think that **ASP.NET MVC** would be the more closest to JSF and so to PrimeFaces. But it haven't a large set of builtin controls based on jQuery as you liked on PrimeFaces. Also, if you only used up to now the vanilla ASP.NET, *the MVC concept can be very confusing to start through a professional project*.

It may be safer to continue with your technology knowledge while learning something totally new. Even so I don't indicate **manos** to your project, although it shows to be very light and stable. Furthermore, with it you would need to "*recreate the wheel*" for many tasks that ASP.NET knows to do well within the standards and such.

Based on these arguments, it seems that in your case you (or your team) is so familiar with ASP.NET that your immediate need is to use good tools to improve the shortcomings of ASP.NET on HTML5, web standards and themes. *Then you don't need to change everything you knows right now, just improve what you already know* (and of course we recommend that you consider these other approaches gradually).

So let a few helpful hints for you:

- First read about and download a sample of **a good architecture using HTML5, jQuery and jQuery UI**. [This post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/11/building-an-html5-app-with-asp-net.aspx) covers all those technologies and have the full source code to download.
- Also **have in mind that you don't need start your project from scratch**. There is the great [HTML5 BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) which comes with dozens of good pratices (and a nice *Web.config* created with many nice ideas). Important note that it's also based on jQuery as you want.
- Maybe you already have some incredible themes created for PrimeFaces and you would like to use on your ASP.NET projet. Then remember: **to take advantage of the jQuery UI Themes you just needs using `class` names and DOM hierarchy**. If your PrimeFaces Complex DataTable gerenates an incredible HTML which is so beautifull with your CSS, just use the same generated HTML inside a UserControl so you can reuse it around all yours pages without needing rewriting all the HTML.
- Also remember that **PrimeFaces is opensource and because of it you always can open the sources**, read the jQuery codes and reuse what you really think are perfect for you.

Then, finally, there are many tools and approaches to support you enjoy what you've done with PrimeFaces and also enjoy your existing knowledge in ASP.NET. Unfortunately we don't have done something like this to ASP.NET, but maybe what you'll do will be so good that you can publish opensource for everyone?

Comment: Your considerations was very good and the suggested links was much usefull. I think your answer is the right way to me.

Comment: good answer. i especially liked the "why dont you create an awesome asp.net open source library?" part :)

Answer (score 2):

PrimeFaces for ASP.NET is announced. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2128

Comment: The most incredible news of the day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need ASP.Net MVC instead of ASP.Net Web Forms, this gives you much more control.

You have the asp.net mvc html helpers toolkit, see: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/16/asp-net-mvc-meets-html5.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm really thinking about ASP.NET MVC since JSF is based on MVC concepts too. But the HTML5 Helpers seems so crude... I hope can find something with many controls (can be HTML5 or just XHTML 1.1) and fully based on jQuery and jQuery UI for theming.

Comment: Erick, ASP.NET MVC is really the way to go for what you want if you want to use .NET for this sort of thing. I somewhat doubt that a library exists that does what you want (because Raynos is correct in that progressive enhancement _is_ the way to go), but building the important bits on top of Razor is not that difficult. I think the library I use for my own projects took maybe a weekend to build. (It may get open-sourced at some point, but not in the near future).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of great open-source .NET integrated UIs, but [Telerik RadControls](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx) are themeable (sp?), standards compliant, integrated with ASP.NET, and built with jQuery. They are really great if you have a few hundred dollars to burn.

Otherwise, [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) is integrated with ASP.NET and open source but I'm not crazy about it. It's not based on jQuery but I think it is standards compliant.

Sadly, the open source communities tend to shy away from .NET (and Microsoft in general).

Answer (score 1):

[PrimeFaces For .NET Cancelled](https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-for-net-cancelled/)

> PrimeFaces for ASP.NET WebForms project has been cancelled after two releases and as PrimeTek we have decided not to do further investments. Instead of .NET, our secondary focus will be PrimeUI who is very close to 1.0 release already and can be used with any web framework.

You can check out the [PrimeUI](https://www.primefaces.org/primeui/) library which is:

> a collection of rich javascript widgets based on jQuery UI. PrimeUI is a spin-off from the popular JavaServer Faces Component Suite, PrimeFaces.