# Primefaces Component Use in Plain Html File

Tags: java, javascript, html, primefaces

I wanted to use this primefaces component, [picklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5WP4.png), in a plain local html file. I don't want to use a server, I just need the component and use it locally. My question is that how can I import this primefaces component into a simple html file?

Basically, I want to use this component locally.

Comment: You can't. If you want to use the primefaces component directly in your page, you **have to** use it in a JSP or in a Facelets page. Otherwise, you could copy its HTML/JavaScript/CSS from the component sources and use that in your project (but I don't think you will get what you expect).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921281/is-there-something-equivalent-to-primefaces-for-asp-net <-- In the ticked answer, they state that it is possible. I am not sure how :( In the end, isn't it just plain css, javascript and html?

Comment: I read the Q/A and can't find where they state that this is possible. And this component (as others PrimeFaces components) has its HTML, JavaScript and CSS code **in its sources** that are free to see and copy/paste/use it wherever you want/need, but you have to review that and adapt it to your code and your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use primeUI for this purpose. you can download the css and js files and import them in your plain html file. see http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/index.html

Comment: Thanks! However, i cannot seem to find one for the picklist component. Do you know anyway else i can retrieve a picklist primefaces component?

Comment: primefaces is based on jquery-ui for its' ui elements. If you search internet for jquery-ui picklist, you'll come across lots of stuff. @user2546267

Comment: primefaces does not use jquery-ui for all the elements, only 3-4 components are jQuery UI based, rest are developed in house.

Comment: Thanks, I have search around and found this picklist component. https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/

Answer (score 0):

New version of PrimeUI has the PickList of PrimeFaces;

http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/picklist.html